# How to fetch list of files from S3 without lexicographic order

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I want to delete the files in the s3 where file last modified date is greater than our retention policy. When am trying to list the Object Summaries it is giving in lexicographic order because of this my top 1000 files last modified date is less than our retention policy and not able to delete till it exceeds that date. So is there any method or process for Object Listing with ascending order of last modified date in Java?

Comment: Why don't you use S3 Lifecycle Policies to delete the files older than X days?

Comment: The [underlying API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html) does not support any sort order other than by key name.  The only option is to list all objects and sort/filter on the client side, or as mentioned, use a [S3 Lifecycle Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) to automate this on the backend.

Comment: Thank you, issue got resolved with life cycle policy.